# Difference between Have to and had to

Tags: tense

I just watched episode one of Rick and Morty. Rick said “ I had to make a bomb” why would he used had to instead of have to when he has not yet make a bomb?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps he said *I had to make a bomb* because he changed his mind and now he doesn't consider it necassary to make it or the situation changed somehow where he isn't required to make a bomb anymore. Or perhaps he needed to make a bomb at a particalar time in the past, but he didn't manage to make it. As you can see it's hard to say what he meant by that without much context.

Comment: The story is about Rick wakes up Morty and get on a fly vehicle that he built. After that Rick says to Morty “ I had to make a bomb, Morty....I had to create a bomb..” “ We’re going to drop it down there, it’s going to get a whole fresh start. “ After that Morty somehow stops him. Can I consider that the reason why he used had to is because this is something he should do it in the past but he did no do it and now he decided to do it again. Hope you understand my poor English..

Comment: The sentence "I had to make a bomb" means "I was compelled to make a bomb". If he decided to make a bomb but he didn't make it, then he could say, "I was supposed to make a bomb, but I didn't". But "had to" means something was obligatory to do and it was done.

Comment: I must say I am not a native speaker, but I have watched the part and it's obvious that he has actuall built the bomb, that's why he said "I had to make a bomb" meaning he doesn't have to make now because he already has one.   There is the scene where the robot voice in the ship says "arming neutrino bomb" and Morty, thinking that Rick is going to drop the bomb, starts fighting with Rick over control of the wheel.